# Social sharing conflict with Rewrite rules

Tags: rewrite-rules, social-sharing

I have created a custom plugin that adds a rewrite rule so that a url like this
`http://domain.com/listings/property/123456`
will resolve to the page 'listings'. That works great. 
I also have removed the default WordPress canonical url and added my own to match the rewrite rule so then on that page the canonical url shows like

`<link rel='canonical' href='http://domain.com/listings/property/123456' />`

However when a social sharing plugin like AddToAny is installed and shows on that page, it doesn't grab the full url for sharing - instead just grabs the url of the WordPress page itself -- http://domain.com/listings

When I look at what they are doing in the code for that plugin they are making a call to get_permalink() for the page and using that for sharing.

Any ideas on ways to overcome this? I don't think dynamically setting the permalink will solve the problem - that would probably break the original rewrite rule. Perhaps there is another WordPress action that would be helpful?

Comment: What is a property exactly? Where does that data come from? I don't see how filtering the output of `get_permalink` would break a rewrite rule, what is the logic behind that?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Here is what the rewrite rule does. `domain.com/listings/property/123456 --> domain.com/listings/?property=123456`. Even if I use the second example, passing a variable called property to the page (and not use a rewrite rule), the social sharing plugins will strip off the variable at the end and just try and share "domain.com/listings". I want to somehow prevent that stripping from happening.

Comment: Filtering the output of `get_permalink` seems appropriate in this case.

Comment: Thank you @Milo for your help with this. Yes, I do need to somehow filter the output of get_permalink. However my attempts at doing that have been unsuccessful. 

I have tried this where I add a test parameter to the permalink.

    function append_query_string($url, $post) {
      $url = add_query_arg("param","value", $url);
      return $url;
    }
    add_filter('post_type_link', 'append_query_string', 10,2);

but that doesn't work. When I output `get_the_permalink()` afterwards it still has the original permalink, without the parameter added.

Comment: Sorry - can't seem to get a block of code to display correctly in a comment.

Comment: The `post_type_link` filter is only applied to custom post types, if it is a `page` post type, then you need to filter `page_link`.

Comment: Fantastic - that solved it. I had tried post_type_link and post_link filters. Wasn't aware there was a page_link filter. Thanks!